# Get ActiveX Content and save it to file with C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, activex, webbrowser-control

I have to write a small web robot to get the content of a web site.
But on one of the pages the result is an ActiveX control:

```
<OBJECT ID="CRViewer"
    CLASSID="CLSID:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    WIDTH=100% HEIGHT=99%
    CODEBASE="viewer/ActiveXControls/ActiveXViewer.cab#Version=XXXXXX" VIEWASTEXT>
<PARAM NAME="EnableRefreshButton" VALUE=1>
<PARAM NAME="EnableGroupTree" VALUE=1>
<PARAM NAME="DisplayGroupTree" VALUE=1>
<PARAM NAME="EnablePrintButton" VALUE=1>
<PARAM NAME="EnableExportButton" VALUE=1>
<PARAM NAME="EnableDrillDown" VALUE=1>
<PARAM NAME="EnableSearchControl" VALUE=1>
<PARAM NAME="EnableAnimationControl" VALUE=0>
<PARAM NAME="EnableZoomControl" VALUE=1>
</OBJECT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
<!--
Sub Window_Onload
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim webBroker
    Set webBroker = CreateObject("CrystalReports11.WebReportBroker.1")
    Dim webSource
    Set webSource = CreateObject("CrystalReports11.WebReportSource.1")
    webSource.ReportSource = webBroker
    webSource.URL = "rptserver.asp"
    webSource.PromptOnRefresh = True
    CRViewer.ReportSource = webSource
    CRViewer.ViewReport
End Sub
-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Now, I have the content of the web page in a **System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser**.
I can make:

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement ele = formBrowser.Document.GetElementById("CRViewer");
```

But then I am stuck with the params tags of the Object, not with its content.
And as a whole the ActiveX control is not shown from my program. When I access the page with IE I see the **CrystalReports** result but till now I can not make the report to appear from within my program. 
Any advices are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with? Don't `<param>` tags show up in `ele.OuterHtml`?

Comment: Yes. But this ActiveX console must show a CrystalReports file, which is some kind of document. I don't need the tags, I need the document itself.